If $G$ is an additive group, $u,v$ endomorphisms, then if $h(x)= x-u(v(x))$ is onto then $f(x)= x-v(u(x))$ is onto
Let $G$ be an additive group, and $u,v\colon G \to G$ homomorphisms. I have to show that the map $f\colon G \to G$, $f(x)=x-v(u(x))$ is surjective if the map $h\colon G\to G$, $h(x)=x-u(v(x))$ is surjective.
Since $h$ is surjective, I wanted to play with the kernels of both $h$ and $f$, and I managed to show that they are isomorphic:

Consider the map $\lambda\colon \mathrm{Ker}(h) \to \mathrm{Ker}(f)$ given by $x\mapsto v(x)$. One can see that $x\in \mathrm{Ker}(f)$ if and only if $u(x)\in \mathrm{Ker}(h)$ and similarly $y\in \mathrm{Ker}(h)$ if and only if $v(y)\in \mathrm{Ker}(f)$. If $\lambda(x)=v(x)=0$, then $h(x) = x$, but since $x\in\mathrm{Ker}(h)$ we have $x=0$. Now, if $y\in \mathrm{Ker}(f)$ then $y=v(u(y))$, but since $u(y)\in \mathrm{Ker}(h)$ then $\lambda$ is surjective.

Now, I know that in general if $H\cong K$ then it is not necessarily the case that $G/H\cong G/K$, but I am very tempted to show that $G/\mathrm{Ker}(f) \cong G/\mathrm{Ker}(h)\cong G$ so that $f$ is surjective. I tried defining the map $x+\mathrm{Ker}(h)\mapsto v(x)+\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ but I am not sure if this map is in fact surjective. Perhaps this is not right, but I want a hint on how to follow, or if this is not the right approach.

Given $y$, we want to find $x$ such that $(1 - vu)(x) = y$ ($1$ stands for the identity map). By assumption, there exists $z$ such that $(1 - uv)(z) = u(y)$. Now put $x = y + v(z)$, and check that this works.

This is related to an old chestnut (sometimes used in functional analysis to prove results about the spectrum of an operator): if $1 - uv$ is invertible, then so is $1 - vu$.
"Proof": $(1 - vu)^{-1} = 1 + vu + vuvu + vuvuvu + \ldots = 1 + v(1 + uv + uvuv + \ldots)u = 1 + v(1 - uv)^{-1} u$.
Of course the first and last steps are invalid, but the end result is a formula for the inverse that one can check is correct!
The way that I got the proof above is to adapt this idea, but just to the surjectivity hypothesis.
